# Dart Isolates - How to access a specific one?

Tags: dart, dart-isolates

How can I create an Isolate n°2 from an Isolate n°1 and give it some sort of identification ? The goal would be to be able to communicate with it from Isolate n°3, despite that third Isolate not having a SendPort letting it talk to Isolate n°2.
Isolate n°3 would have to create a SendPort from the identification choosen.

EDIT :
I have found IsolateNameServer from the Flutter team, and https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/44495 mentions using the Registry functionality instead. Is there any resources/examples talking about these 2 solutions ?

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen any direct way to attach an identity to a specific Isolate.

Isolates get IDs as soon as they're generated.
You may retrieve the specific ID of an Isolate by the example below:

```
import 'dart:isolate';    
import 'dart:developer';

void isolateExample(var n){   
  // displaying 5*5 result and the specific Isolate's ID
  print('Result is: ${n*n} and it has the Isolate ID: ');
  print(Service.getIsolateID(Isolate.current));   
}    

void main() async{
  // producing an Isolate to perform a computation 5*5
  await Isolate.spawn(isolateExample,5);   
}

// Output: 25 and **it has the Isolate ID: isolates/189015374367763**
```

Comment: Just one thing to note: this works but uses the developer package which replies on the vm service which is *not* available when Dart code is AOT compiled.